# android - Picasso with OkHTTP can not load images containing vertical bar character ( "|" ) in their URL

Tags: gradle, mapbox, picasso, okhttp

I use Picasso and MapBox in my project. As long as MapBox has OkHTTP in it's dependecies, I'm forced to use OkHTTP.
But when I add OkHTTP to gradle dependencies, Picasso becomes unable to load images containing vertical bar character ( "|" ) in their URL.

Without OkHTTP:

`Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/image.jpg").into(imageView); //OK
Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/image.jpg|100:100").into(imageView); //OK`

With OkHTTP:

`Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/image.jpg").into(imageView);
 //09-01 19:07:35.280  24916-24916/com.test D/Picasso﹕ Main        errored      [R6]+287ms`

`Picasso.with(context).load("http://example.com/image.jpg|100:100").into(imageView); //OK`

So, my question is: How to avoid using OkHTTP with Picasso if another library needs OkHTTP or how to resolve this problem and continue using OkHTTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by adding the next code in `MyApplication.onCreate()` method:

```
    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .requestTransformer(new Picasso.RequestTransformer() {
                @Override
                public Request transformRequest(Request request) {
                    Uri oldImageUri = request.uri;
                    Uri newImageUri = oldImageUri.buildUpon().query(oldImageUri.getEncodedQuery()).build();
                    return request.buildUpon().setUri(newImageUri).build();
                }
            }).build();
    picasso.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    Picasso.setSingletonInstance(picasso);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try OkHttp 2.5.0. It supports URLs containing the `|` character.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I started using OkHttp. The issue seems to be that the vertical bar character must be encoded. Just replace it with the encoded value (%7C) and it should work fine. In your case the url becomes:

```
http://example.com/image.jpg%7C100:100
```